# wget command in shell script with & in url

Tags: shell, wget

php code

```
<?php
system("/var/www/yes/project/xxe.sh > /tmp/a.txt 2>&1");
?>
```

in `xxe.sh`

```
$(wget -O sample.html http://www.vtualerts.com/results/get_res.php?usn=1PE11mca$i&sem=2)
```

But this is not saving the proper page
I tried escaping & (by \&) this will run in terminal but not from php

Comment: Put it in "<double-quotes>". Also try- string escapeshellcmd ( string $command )

Comment: Does php know about the `$i` variable in the URL?

Comment: yes I hav used for loop

Comment: not working with double-qoutes